# XSLT processing with Java?

Tags: java, xslt

How to transform XML with XSLT processor in Java using the JDK?

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for pointers to Saxon's documentation and for an important notice that in many cases one doesn't need to know Java in order to use a Java-based XSLT processor.

Comment: This answer has a precise answer, and it is not very obvious to a newcomer what the answer is. This question should be reopened.

Comment: On topic, since..you know, using programmer tools in a programmer language is off topic here...smh.

Answer (score 168):

Here is sample for using java api for transformer, as @Raedwald said:

```
import javax.xml.transform.*;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamResult;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamSource;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URISyntaxException;

public class TestMain {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, URISyntaxException, TransformerException {
        TransformerFactory factory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
        Source xslt = new StreamSource(new File("transform.xslt"));
        Transformer transformer = factory.newTransformer(xslt);

        Source text = new StreamSource(new File("input.xml"));
        transformer.transform(text, new StreamResult(new File("output.xml")));
    }
}
```

The input can also be from a string or DOMSource, the output can be to a DOMSource [etc](http://www.microhowto.info/howto/process_an_xml_document_using_an_xslt_stylesheet_in_java.html).

Comment: What a well-written example!! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 12):

> I am new to xslt. Can anybody guide me
>   how to xslt processing with java?

**This depends on which Java-based XSLT processor you are using. Each XSLT processor has its own API.**

For example, Saxon 6.5.5 (for XSLT 1.0) and Saxon 9.1.07 (for XSLT 2.0) are written in Java. The documentation is at **http://www.saxonica.com/documentation/documentation.xml**

**Almost all XSLT processors have a command-line utility**, which doesn't require writing a program in order to perform an XSLT transformation.

For example, **[here is](http://www.saxonica.com/documentation/using-xsl/commandline.xml)**: **how to start a Saxon 9.x transformation from the command line**.

**Here is how I always use Saxon from the command-line**:

```
java -Xms2048M  -Xmx10000M  -jar  
     C:\xml\Parsers\Saxon\Ver.9.1.0.7\J\saxon9.jar 
    -t  -repeat:1  -o %out%  %xml%  %xsl%  %param[ name=\"value\"]%
```

where `%out%` is the name of the output file, `%xml%` is the xml file, `%xsl%` is the primary xslt file and `%param[ name=\"value\"]%` is a name-value list of external parameters (I almost always leave this empty).

Comment: There's a standard API for XSLT, see the package `javax.xml.transform`. I'd use that in favor of any third-party library with its own API, unless there's some compelling reason for using a specific third-party library.

Comment: @Jesper: We are *fortunate* that using APIs is not the only way! The majority of XSLT programmers that use any XSLT processor are *not* Java programmers. It would be a totally unfortunate and unjustified loss if they were deprived from using such great XSLT processors as Saxon or Xalan. In fact, producing Java-based XSLT processors that required Java programming in order to use them, wouldn't be profitable at all.

Comment: @Dimitre But the question was about how to do XSLT processing with Java; talking about other ways to do it (not via an API) is not relevant. If you're going to do it using some API, use the standard API unless there is a compelling reason to use some non-standard API.

Comment: @Jesper: Not to make known the way of using an XSLT processor without any programming would be a disservice to the OP and any other reader and would mislead them to believe that writing a program was the only way to do this. My answer is a clear message: There *is* a better and more convenient way; write a program only if you *have* to.

Answer (score 10):

The Java standard library provides an (XSLT) transformation interface for XML parsing. See the API documentation for the classes [`javax.xml.transform.Transformer`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/transform/Transformer.html) and `javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory`.

Answer (score 6):

JAXP provides a implementation independent way of working with XSLT transformations. [Here is the tutorial](http://onjava.com/pub/a/onjava/excerpt/java_xslt_ch5/index.html?page=4) to get you started. If you are working with huge XSLT and/or working with multiple XSLT's then there is also an option of caching the parsed XSLT templates for performance reasons. [This article](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-05-2003/jw-0502-xsl.html) explains how to cache xslt's

Comment: this is gone, it seems.