# Extract all SOAP XML nodes text only, in Java

Tags: java, xml, dom, sax

I have the following SOAP XML from which I want to extract the text content of all nodes:

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2001/12/soap-envelope" soap:encodingStyle="http://www.w3.org/2001/12/soap-encoding"
    xmlns:m="http://www.example.org/stock">
    <soap:Body>
        <m:GetStockName>
            <m:StockName>ABC</m:StockName>
        </m:GetStockName>
        <!--some comment-->
        <m:GetStockPrice>
            <m:StockPrice>10 \n </m:StockPrice>
            <m:StockPrice>\t20</m:StockPrice>
        </m:GetStockPrice>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

The exptected output would be:

```
'ABC10 \n \t20'
```

I've done the following in **DOM**:

```
public static String parseXmlDom() throws ParserConfigurationException,
        SAXException, IOException, FileNotFoundException {

    DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
    // Read XML File
    String xml = IOUtils.toString(new FileInputStream(new File(
            "./files/request2.xml")), "UTF-8");
    InputSource is = new InputSource(new StringReader(xml));
    // Parse XML String to DOM
    factory.setNamespaceAware(true);
    factory.setIgnoringComments(true);
    Document doc = builder.parse(is);
    // Extract nodes text
    NodeList nodeList = doc.getElementsByTagNameNS("*", "*");
    Node node = nodeList.item(0);
    return node.getTextContent();
}
```

And with **SAX**:

```
public static String parseXmlSax() throws SAXException, IOException, ParserConfigurationException {

    final StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
    SAXParserFactory factory = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
    SAXParser saxParser = factory.newSAXParser();
    // Declare Handler
    DefaultHandler handler = new DefaultHandler() {
        public void characters(char ch[], int start, int length) throws SAXException {
            sb.append((new String(ch, start, length)));
        }
    };
    // Parse XML
    saxParser.parse("./files/request2.xml", handler);
    return sb.toString();
}
```

For both aproaches I receive:

```
'


            ABC



            10 \n 
            \t20


'
```

I know I could easily put `return sb.toString().replaceAll("\n", "").replaceAll("\t", "");` to achieve the expected result, but if my XML file is badly formatted, with extra spaces for example, the result would include that extra spaces too.

Also, I've tried [this approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5511096/java-convert-formatted-xml-file-to-one-line-string) to read the XML as a single line before parsing it with SAX or DOM, but it does not work for my SOAP XML example as it trims the spaces between the `soap:Envelope` properties when there are breaklines (`xmlns:m`):

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2001/12/soap-envelope" soap:encodingStyle="http://www.w3.org/2001/12/soap-encoding"xmlns:m="http://www.example.org/stock"><soap:Body><m:GetStockName><m:StockName>ABC</m:StockName></m:GetStockName><m:GetStockPrice><m:StockPrice>10 \n  </m:StockPrice><m:StockPrice>\t20</m:StockPrice></m:GetStockPrice></soap:Body></soap:Envelope>
[Fatal Error] :1:129: Element type "soap:Envelope" must be followed by either attribute specifications, ">" or "/>".
```

How can I read just the text content of all nodes in a SOAP XML no matter if the XML file consists in a single line or multiple well/badly formatted lines (ignoring comments too)?

Comment: Is there a reason you can't use a SOAP parser like Axis2?

Comment: Can you provide some example? I only know about DOM and SAX. I may use other libraries but only if they are supported by Java 1.6.0.