# How to pass XML file content into java command as command line argument?

Tags: java, xml, groovy

I have one `xml` file. I want to pass the `xml` content into java command line argument.

**abc.xml** :

```
   <a>
    <block1>abc</block1>
    <block2>xyz</block2>
    <block3>pqr</block3>
    </a>
```

Below is my `groovy`/`java` code to get data from file and pass it into java command line argument.

```
File fl = new File("PATH/abc.xml")
String filecontent = fl.getText()
String cmd = "Java -cp abc.jar package.CLASSNAME "+filecontent 
Process proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);
proc.waitFor()
```

This command is not executing just comes out of process.
Why??

Comment: `java -cp abc.jar package.CLASSNAME "$(cat PATH/abc.xml)"` is enough. Don't write programs.

Comment: Sorry i forget to mention i am doing it in windows machine, and when i get text which contains \n and spaces in between so it doesn't consider it as single argument, i tried [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5511096/java-convert-formatted-xml-file-to-one-line-string) but not working...

Comment: Quoting should make spaces harmless. But on windows (unless it has improved in recent versions) the length restriction for command lines may hurt you.

Comment: Not sure why you are sending xml string as argument? How about send the file name and read file inside java program?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Untested code off the top of my head, so take it for what it's worth:

```
File fl = new File("PATH/abc.xml")
String filecontent = fl.readLines().*trim().join(' ')
String cmd = "java -cp abc.jar package.CLASSNAME \"${filecontent}\"" 
Process proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);
proc.waitFor()
```

Since this is Groovy code, I would also change it to invoke package.Classname.main() directly, rather than spinning off a process and another JVM:

```
File fl = new File("PATH/abc.xml")
String filecontent = fl.readLines().*trim().join(' ')
package.CLASSNAME.main([filecontent])
```

Comment: Yes , you are right, but i suppose to run that another JVM code is on server and earlier code on my client side. So i need to start another JVM process independently.