# Fixing malformed XML with java

Tags: java, xml

I have several files containing the following XML element:

```
     <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0"style="width:100%">
```

The part that says `border="0"style="` needs a space between the 0 value and style attribute.

Unfortunately there are too many files with this issue to make manually going and inserting the space a viable option. 
I can edit attributes and I can edit values by creating an Xpath that gets the table as a NodeList, creates a node and gets the attributes.. but how would I add a space between the attribute and the value??

Comment: I don't think you can use XPath, because your input file won't manage to be successfully parsed. I think you should use simple text replacement, programmatically with any language you like.

Comment: ahh okay.. will look into it, cheers..

Comment: @vessel - do you know if the border is always set to a 1 char value? if either border or style have a consistent char length for value, this is super easy

Comment: Take a look at this question - http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/112023/how-can-i-replace-a-string-in-a-files

Comment: How about using a shell tool like `sed`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could always just `String.split("\"");` aka split on the commas.

Here, try this:

```
/** In reality, you would probably read file to string? 
 * or read line by line? either way is an easy fix! 
*/

String input = ("<table cellpadding=\"0\" cellspacing=\"0\" border=\"0\"style=\"width:100%\">");
String xmlTag = StringUtils.substringBetween(input, "<", ">");
```

Starting with index number, array after split contains as follows:

1. XML Tag Name

***ODD INDICES*** ~ 1, 3, 5, and so on, contain: **attribute name.**

***EVEN INDICES*** ~ 2, 4, 6, and so on, contain: **attribute value.**

```
    int arrSize = xmlCharValPairs.length()        
    String[] xmlCharValPairs = xmlTag.split("\"");
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(arrSize);

    sb.append("<" + xmlCharValPairs[0] + " ");

    for (int i = 1; i < arrSize-1; i++) {
        if (i%2 == 0) 
            sb.append("\"" + xmlCharValPairs[i].trim() + "\" ");
        else 
            sb.append(xmlCharValPairs[i]);
    }

    String returnXMLFormat = sb.toString();
```

This will leave you with an XML String in your requested format :)

Answer (score 0):

If it's consistent length then all you need to write is a simple string parser that would add extra "" at X position.

If it's not the same everything I think I would try to check if char is " then a char -1 from it and then check if it's =" or (some letter)" for example a".

```
width="100" vs width="100" anotherparam="...
```

This could tell you if it's begining or end of param. If it's the ending then simply add a space char after it.

Obiously you could then check if it's "(someletter) or "(space) to know if there is space char after your apostrophe.

```
width="100" param2="..." vs width="100"param2=""
```

If you have lets say 200 files to edit you could use something similar to this:

```
File folder = new File("your/path");
File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles();
```

Then simply open files in a loop, edit them and save them to new files with their orginal names or just overwrite current files. It's up to you.

Answer (score 0):

Your file isn't well-formed XML so you will need a tool that can handle files that aren't well-formed XML. That rules anything in the XSLT/XQuery/XPath family.

You can probably fix nearly all occurrences of the problem, with low risk of adverse side effects, by using a regular expression that inserts a space after any occurrence of `"` that isn't immediately preceded by `=`. (This will add some unnecessary spaces, but the XML parser will ignore them.)

Comment: Thanks, I actually ended up using a variation of the info here:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5511096/java-convert-formatted-xml-file-to-one-line-string  which allowed me to use a simple replaceAll().