# Pass the XML file content to a java method

Tags: java, xml, unit-testing

I am doing a unit testing.

there is a method where xml need to be passed , in the method the parameter type is `String` I have the xml file in my laptop.

can some one suggest me how we can pass this xml file data to the method ?

Comment: please let me know if my question is not clear or need more clarification

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java : Convert formatted xml file to one line string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5511096/java-convert-formatted-xml-file-to-one-line-string)

Comment: Read your XML File with BufferedReader and then append with StringBuffer

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Read file As String](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12910503/read-file-as-string)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> need more clarification

I guess, that the String varibale is the path name of the xml-file
on your laptop: e.g.

```
"D:\\temp\\the_xmlfile.xml"
```

Comment: no Norbert .. I printed the value which is going into the java method. its a proper XML - (LONG type - Oracle PL/SQL). the overall scenario is a PL/SQL package is calling a java class , I inserted the parameter value,which is going into the java class into a table and now am testing the java code