# Convert unformatted XML to formatted XML at once

Tags: java

I am currently in need of processing a formatted XML to an unformatted single line XML. I had gone through [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5511176/8595958) SO answer for my reference.

However, my formatted XML string has 3500 lines. On using the method mentioned on the above answer shared, it is currently taking more than 18ms for processing my XML.

Is there a faster way to do this, at the rate of 5ms for 3500 lines?

Comment: Is 18 milliseconds really too long? Are you sure this isn't premature optimization?

Comment: I will be received thousands of request XML per second Slaw. And 18ms is slow for that.

Comment: Can you make any assumptions about the incoming XML? For example, can you assume that there are not line-break characters that you have to retain? If you can make this assumption then you can just replace all line-breaks by blanks.