# Java: Implementing Transform View pattern, to convert XML to HTML with an XSL file

Tags: java, xml, xslt, design-patterns

I have read the Oracle tutorial: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxp/xslt/transformingXML.html

The w3school guide: https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xsl_intro.asp

And a StackOverflow's thread: [XSLT processing with Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4604497/xslt-processing-with-java)

I am learning the Transform View pattern and I would like to implement it in Java.

I have created an XML file, Alumnos.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<ALUMNO>
    <NOMBRE>Luis</NOMBRE>
    <APPELLIDO1>Navarro</APPELLIDO1>
    <APPELLIDO2>Morote</APPELLIDO2>
    <ASIGNATURAS>
        <ASIGNATURA>PR4</ASIGNATURA>
        <NOTA>5</NOTA>
        <ASIGNATURA>BD2</ASIGNATURA>
        <NOTA>8</NOTA>
        <ASIGNATURA>IR</ASIGNATURA>
        <NOTA>10</NOTA>
    </ASIGNATURAS>
</ALUMNO>
```

And a Xsl file, called Alumnos.xsl

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet 
    xmlns:xsl=
    "http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
    version="1.0"
>

    <xsl:template match="ALUMNO">
        <HTML>
            <BODY bgcolor="gray">
                <xsl:apply-templates/>
            </BODY>
        </HTML>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="NOMBRE">
        <P>
            <B>Nombre: </B>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </P>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="ASIGNATURA">
        <h1>Aginatura: </h1>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:output method="html"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Currently I have the following Java class, AlumnosCommand.java:

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package frontController;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.xml.transform.Transformer;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerConfigurationException;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerException;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamResult;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamSource;

/**
 *
 * @author YonePC
 */
@WebServlet(name = "AlumnosCommand", urlPatterns = {"/AlumnosCommand"})
public class AlumnosCommand extends FrontCommand {

    /**
     * Processes requests for both HTTP <code>GET</code> and <code>POST</code>
     * methods.
     *
     * @param request servlet request
     * @param response servlet response
     * @throws ServletException if a servlet-specific error occurs
     * @throws IOException if an I/O error occurs
     */
    protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
        PrintWriter writer = response.getWriter();
        writer.println("<h1>Hi</h1>");

    }

    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="HttpServlet methods. Click on the + sign on the left to edit the code.">
    /**
     * Handles the HTTP <code>GET</code> method.
     *
     * @param request servlet request
     * @param response servlet response
     * @throws ServletException if a servlet-specific error occurs
     * @throws IOException if an I/O error occurs
     */
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        processRequest(request, response);
    }

    /**
     * Handles the HTTP <code>POST</code> method.
     *
     * @param request servlet request
     * @param response servlet response
     * @throws ServletException if a servlet-specific error occurs
     * @throws IOException if an I/O error occurs
     */
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        processRequest(request, response);
    }

    /**
     * Returns a short description of the servlet.
     *
     * @return a String containing servlet description
     */
    public String getServletInfo() {
        return "Short description";
    }// </editor-fold>

    @Override
    public void process(HttpServletRequest request) {
        try {

            TransformerFactory factory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
            StreamSource xls = new StreamSource(new File("Alumnos.xsl"));
            Transformer newTransformer = factory.newTransformer(xls);

            StreamSource xml = new StreamSource(new File("Alumnos.xml"));
            newTransformer.transform(xml, new StreamResult(new File("output.xml")));

            forward("/Alumnos.jsp");

        } catch (ServletException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(AlumnosCommand.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(AlumnosCommand.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (TransformerException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(AlumnosCommand.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }

}
```

The above class has the purpose of reading the xml, and transform it with the xls and convert it into a new xml file (it should be later used to print the actual HTML for the page).

The difficulty I am facing is that when I press on the 'See pupils list':

[image]

The AlumnosCommand.java appears totally blank:

[image]

I thought it could be a routing /server problem but it is okay, because if I delete the lines related to load xml and convert it, we see the AlumnosCommand.java

[image]

***How could I use the given XML file with the proposed XSL rules, to convert it into HTML and render it into the AlumnosCommand.java page?***

As a note I include the app's architecture:
[image]

Comment: So what do you expect to be rendered if you write with `newTransformer.transform(xml, new StreamResult(new File("output.xml")));` to a file? Shouldn't you write the transformation to `response.getWriter()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `process()` method is transforming the `Alumnos.xml` into `output.xml` using `Alumnos.xsl`. This `output.xml` will have all the `HTML` code and it will be created in the same location as your XML and XSL files. The request is then forwarded to `Alumnos.jsp`. Does this `JSP` file perform reading from `output.xml` to print anything? My guess is no and hence you are not seeing anything on the web page.

The `process()` needs to be modified to write the transformation to a `Writer` object e.g. `PrintWriter`. `HttpServletResponse` already has a `getWriter()` method which will help in printing the output. Below is the sample code that would do it.

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
    try {
        TransformerFactory factory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
        StreamSource xsl = new StreamSource(new File("Alumnos.xsl"));
        Transformer newTransformer = factory.newTransformer(xsl);

        StreamSource xml = new StreamSource(new File("Alumnos.xml"));
        PrintWriter writer = response.getWriter();
        Result result = new StreamResult(writer);
        newTransformer.transform(xml, result);
    } catch (IOException ioe) {
        ioe.printStackTrace();
    } catch (TransformerException te) {
        te.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Aniket V for your great reply it worked as expected: I have two questions What should I need to do to use relative paths to the xml and xsl files instead of absolute ones? Second: When I output the PrintWriter using: writer.println(writer.toString()) it also shows the java's object's reference like java.sun.com etc how could I delete it? THANK YOU for your help.

Comment: (1) For relative paths of the XML and XSL files, you can place them at the `classpath` of the `.war` or `.ear` whichever deployable you are using. This will ensure that absolute path is not hardcoded and your deployment does not throw exceptions on the server. (2) Since you are using `writer.toString()`, Java is converting the object into string and providing the reference. You can check `writer.getBuffer().toString()` for the content. If that doesn't work check the `Javadocs` for `Writer` interface and its available methods to retrieve the content.