# How to parse HTML elements recursively

Tags: java, recursion, html-parsing

I have below HTML which needs to be parsed recursively. I am using Jericho html parser lib for this. However not able to achieve the recursion. Pointers are appreciated!

**HTML**

```
<div wicket:id="Container1">
        <div wicket:id="Panel1"></div>
        <form wicket:id="sampleForm" action="">
            <div id="InterstitialPanel" class="usaa-interstitial s1"></div>
            <div wicket:id="DisclosureSection">
                <div class="sample class">
                    <ul>
                        <li>Item 1</li>
                        <li>Item 2</li>
                        <li>Item 3</li>
                        <li>Item 4</li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form> 
    </div>

    <div wicket:id="Container2">
        <h2>This is container 2</h2>
    </div>
```

**Expected O/p**

Here, I am fetching a value of `wicket:id` from original html and creating a new tag out of it. If it is a standard HTML tag (without wicket attributes), keep it as is.

```
<Container1> 
<Panel1></Panel1>
<Form id="sampleForm">
    <InterstitialPanel></InterstitialPanel>
    <DisclosureSection>
        <div class="sample class">
                    <ul>
                        <li>Item 1</li>
                        <li>Item 2</li>
                        <li>Item 3</li>
                        <li>Item 4</li>
                    </ul>
        </div>
    </DisclosureSection>
</Form>
```

This is container 2

**Java Code**

````
public static void main(String args[]){
 Main m = new Main();
 File file = new File("C:\\USAAPoC\\ClientSamplePage.html");
 Source doc = new Source(file);
 Element element = doc.getElementByTag("body");
 m.processBody(element, new ReactPageContext());
}

private StringBuilder processBody(Element element, ReactPageContext reactPageContext) {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        if (!element.getChildElements().isEmpty()) {
            element.getChildElements().stream().forEach(child -> sb.append(processTag(child, reactPageContext)));
        } else {
            sb.append("<Container>\n");
        }

        return sb;
    }
    
    
private StringBuilder processTag(Element element, ReactPageContext reactPageContext) {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        element.getAllElements().stream().forEach(child -> {
                if (child.getName().equals("div") && child.getAttributes().get("wicket:id") != null) {
                    sb.append("<Container>");
                } else if (child.getName().equals("form")) {
                        
                        sb.append("<Form>"
                        List<Element> allChildFormElements = outputDocument.getSegment().getAllElements();
                        allChildFormElements.stream().forEach(childFormElement -> {
                            if (childFormElement.getName().equals("div")
                                    && childFormElement.getAttributes().get("wicket:id") != null) {
                                    sb.append("<Container>");
                            } else {
                                //logic
                            }
                        });
                }
        });

        return sb;
    }```
````

Answer (score 0):

It seems your processTag method cares about creating start tags (`<Container>`) but never adds end tags (`</Container>`). On top of that you are serializing the dom tree to a String, adding a lot of quirkiness if not done right.

In total you might be better off by using XSLT to replace a tag, then use Java's builtin serializers to obtain the XML document.This is shown in essence in [XSLT processing with Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4604497/xslt-processing-with-java)